# Como exibir um erro ajax através de uma url?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eu tenho um campo de login/senha, quando algum usuário não preenche um dos inputs, eu exibo uma mensagem usando ajax assim:

```
$('#loginform').submit(function(event)
            {
                // Values
                var login = $.trim($('#username').val()),
                    pass = $.trim($('#password').val());

                // Check inputs
                if (login.length === 0)
                {
                    // Display message
                    displayError('Por Favor, insira seu nome de usuario!');
                    return false;
                }
                else if (pass.length === 0)
                {
                    // Remove empty login message if displayed
                    formWrapper.clearMessages('Por Favor, insira sua porta!');

                    // Display message
                    displayError('Por Favor, insira sua senha!');
                    return false;
                }
```

Mas, quando o usuário erra a senha ou usuário, ele volta para url de login na seguinte forma:

> http://example.com?erro=senha_incorreta

Como eu faria, pra capturar esse `erro=senha_incorreta` e exibir o mesmo estilo de aviso que é exibido quando o formulário está em branco?
Algo do tipo:

```
if (?erro === senha_incorreta)
                {
                    // Display message
                    displayError('Sua senha está incorreta!');
                    return false;
                }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com um exemplo de como eu faria pra exibir a mensagem quando a tal url fosse requisitada?

Comment: Neste link acredito ter tudo o que você precisa: http://www.blogalizado.com.br/ajax-e-json-com-jquery-e-php/

Comment: Certo, vou ver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Montei um exemplo bem superficial para o seu caso de login. Suponho que você já tenha o formulário, basta alterar os nomes dos campos.

**<sub>LOGIN.PHP</sub>**

```
<?
// PDO - select user
// senha inválida
echo false;

// usuário encontrado
echo true;
?>
```

**<sub>JS</sub>**

```
<script>
$('form').submit( function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url      : 'login.php',
        type     : 'POST',
        data     : { login : $(this).attr('login') , password : $(this).attr('password') }
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function( request )
        {
            if( request == false )
            {
                alert( 'usuário não encontrado :(' )
            }
            else if( request == true )
            {
                alert( 'usuário encontrado :)' )
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

> Um exemplo básico de uma consulta retornando apenas `TRUE/FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você se interesse pela biblioteca ParseURI.

Exemplo de utilização:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>parseUri example</title>
    <script src="/application/html/js/franzenzenhofer/parseUri/parseUri.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
        var uri = "http://www.google.com/?a=foo&b=bar&c=baz";
        var r= document.getElementById('results');
        r.innerHTML = parseUri(uri).queryKey.b
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Página: http://www.javascriptoo.com/parseuri

Download: https://github.com/franzenzenhofer/parseUri/zipball/master

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade você esta exibindo uma mensagem de erro usando jquery e não ajax, pois não existe uma requisição ajax ao servidor solicitando a tal mensagem.

Então segue abaixo um exemplo de função para pegar os parâmetros da URL aberta, usando jquery:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}

if ($.urlParam('erro') == 'senha_incorreta')
                {
                    // Display message
                    displayError('Sua senha está incorreta!');

                    return false;
                }
```

Mas eu faria em php algo assim:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['erro'] == 'senha_incorreta') echo '<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    displayError(\'Sua senha está incorreta!\');
});
</script>';

?>
```